# Django DRF serializer Custom relational fields How to build return value of to_internal_value?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I'm trying to implement something very similar to Djang Rest Framework tutorial [Custom relational fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields).

For the reminder, the provided code snippet is:

```
import time

class TrackListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        duration = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(value.duration))
        return 'Track %d: %s (%s)' % (value.order, value.name, duration)

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackListingField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

And "This custom field would then serialize to the following representation" (quoted in the tutorial):

```
{
    'album_name': 'Sometimes I Wish We Were an Eagle',
    'artist': 'Bill Callahan',
    'tracks': [
        'Track 1: Jim Cain (04:39)',
        'Track 2: Eid Ma Clack Shaw (04:19)',
        'Track 3: The Wind and the Dove (04:34)',
        ...
    ]
}
```

I understand that and have implemented it for my particular case.

What I don't understand is the way to implement `to_internal_value(self, data)` as I want to provide a read-write API.

**I understand that `to_internal_value(self, data)` should return an AlbumTrack object, but I don't understand how to build it. In particular how to get back the Album related id?**

If we post the JSON structure above, `to_internal_value(self, data)` will be called once per track with `'Track 1: Jim Cain (04:39)'`... for `data` values. **I don't see how we can update the tracks model from those `data` values.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to implement writable nested serializers. While nested serializers are read-only by default, the DRF has a section that explains how to implement writable ones: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Since you want the `TrackListingField` to serialize the `Track` model it should inherit from `ModelSerializer`:

```py
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'name', 'duration']
```

You'll then have to override the `create` method for `AlbumSerializer`:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

Please note that the above will make one database query per track. You can make use of `Track.objects.bulk_create` to make only one query to create all tracks.

To answer your initial question about `to_internal_value`, you can see what the default is by adding this `print` statement to the overridden `to_internal_value`:

```py
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        default_return_value = super(TrackSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        print(default_return_value)
        return default_return_value
```

In the case of a `ModelSerializer` the DRF uses an `OrderedDict` output for `to_internal_value`. Your custom `to_internal_value` would have to extract the `order`, `name` and `duration` from the `data` string using a regex, and put them in an `OrderedDict`. However in this case it'd probably be easier to use a dictionary as representation for the tracks.